# Product image not showing in Category Page In Magento 2.1.6

Tags: import, product-images, 404-page, magento2.1.6

I have installed Magento 2.1.6 and import products using csv, After import Products.

I have did below services,  **But Product image not showing on Product list Page. its goes to 404.**

1. upgrade the module
2. Reindex
3. Flush Cach
4. Restart Cron.

Reference:

Product List Page:

[image: Product List page]

404_error Image:

[image]

I have checked Product image path, like

> /media/catalog/product/cache/f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/1/_/1.jpg

but not generated **f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857** this folder in with in cache folder.

I also regenerated static content also., its not works for me Suggest me How to fix this issue.

Comment: I think permission issue you need to set -0777 permission to pub/media folder.

Comment: I already set 777 permission to all the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below command

```
bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: yes, its worked, But why we need to resize image? what is the benefits?

Comment: in actual the resize function regenerates the images urls and regenerates the cache to speed up magento. Correct me if I am wrong.